# FIGMA "Set Variable" new Feature Issue

Tags: variables, updates, figma

The problem occurs when I try to set the variable "[shape] => "Text" to a specific shape in a Figma component and open the modal.
When I navigate in the linked component with the correct "assign Variable", the modifications linked to the assigned variable don't work. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPs4R.png) the modal is opened but the variable remains unchanged.[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqfvo.png)

I try to change the order [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FR8Yg.png), but nothing changed.
only open modal working,
only set variable working,
but both not working

Comment: EDIT: To provide some context, I have a list of tiles, each of which contains variables such as name, place, and so on. When a tile is clicked, I want to open a modal that corresponds to the clicked tile, with matching variables shared between the tile and the modal. However, I noticed that when I apply a specific layer with the "Change Variable Mode" option enabled, the dynamic display doesn't function as expected. 
Strangely, when I switch the variable mode to "Auto," it works as intended.